# Mostrar contenido dependiendo de la hora y minutos PHP

Tags: php, date

Hola gente espero puedan ayudarme.
Tengo este código en php con el cual muestro contenido dependiendo de la hora, funciona bastante bien, pero actualmente solo puedo declarar y usar la hora como pueden ver: `$desde la 1 utc, $hasta las 8 utc`, en ese rango de tiempo se mostrará el link1, pero lo que intento hacer es usar también los minutos 
por ejemplo: que desde la 1:05 utc hasta la 1:10 utc muestre el link1, y así sucesivamente, pero no he logrado dar con una respuesta.

Soy bastante nuevo en la programación así que les agradezco toda la ayuda que puedan darme.

Código completo:

````
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$desde = 1; # 1am - hora colombia son las 8 pm
$hasta = 8; # 8am - hora colombia son las 3 am

$doble = 9; # 9am - hora colombia son las 4 am
$doble2 = 16; #4pm - hora colombia son las 11 am

$triple = 17; # 5pm - hora colombia son las 12 medio dia
$triple2 = 24; #12pm - hora colombia son las 6 pm

$hora_actual = intval(date("H"));

if ($hora_actual >= $desde && $hora_actual <= $hasta) {
    # Aquí la acción que se realice en el horario permitido
    include "links_es/link1.php";
    
}elseif ($hora_actual >= $doble && $hora_actual <= $doble2) {
    # Mostrar un aviso
    include "links_es/link2.php";

} else{
   include "links_es/link3.php";
}

?>```
````

Comment: Ahí está la implementación de las horas, pero ¿Qué has intentado para implementar los minutos? ¿Qué errores te impiden realizarlo?

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo solucioné

Answer (score 0):

La función `date()` sirve para devolver la hora como has hecho en `date("H")` como para devolver otras muchas partes de una fecha, entre ellas el minuto. Tendrías que utilizar `date("i")`, tal que así:

```
<?php

/* Definir previamente, al igual que haces con las horas, las franjas de minutos que quieres incluir en los condicionales de abajo */

/* Lo importante: Declarar el minuto actual junto a la hora */

$hora_actual   = intval(date("H"));
$minuto_actual = intval(date("i"));

/* Incorporarlo posteriormente a los condicionales que tienes debajo */

?>
```

Te recomiendo que le eches un vistazo a la documentación oficial de la función `date()`, ya que cuenta con muchas posibilidades más y se utiliza con bastante frecuencia: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php

Comment: Gracias por responder, si ya había hecho eso, aunque no estaba del todo seguro, solamente que no supe declarar los minutos como con las horas `$desde = 2;` para luego incorporarlo a las condiciones, tal vez habrá sido por el cansancio, pero hoy lo resolví en menos de 10 minutos.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los que respondieron, por ahora funciona, así quedó el código final por si alguno lo necesita:

```
<?php

        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
        $hora1 = 19; # Desde medio dia bogota

        $hora2 = 20; 
        $hora3 = 21;

        $min_1 = 00;
        $min_2 = 05;

        $min2_1 = 06;
        $min2_2 = 10;

        $min3_1 = 11;
        $min3_2 = 15;


        $hora_actual = intval(date("H"));
        $min_actual = intval(date("i"));
        if ($hora_actual + $min_actual >= $hora1 + $min_1 && $hora_actual + 
        $min_actual <= $hora1 + $min_2) {
            # Aquí la acción que se realice en el horario permitido
            echo "ejemplo1";
            
        }elseif ($hora_actual + $min_actual >= $hora1 + $min2_1 && $hora_actual 
        + $min_actual <= $hora1 + $min2_2) {
            # Mostrar un aviso
            echo "ejemplo2";

        }elseif ($hora_actual + $min_actual >= $hora1 + $min3_1 && $hora_actual 
        + $min_actual <= $hora1 + $min3_2) {
            # Mostrar un aviso
            echo "ejemplo3";

        }else{
        echo "ejemplo4";
        }
        ?>
```

Y si tienen sugerencias o saben otra forma en PHP para hacerlo mas compacto y funcional todo es bien recibido. 
 Ya que si quiero configurar para un rango de 5 horas y que cada 5 minutos cambie el contenido, con la forma actual tendría que escribir mucho código y eso no se ve nada funcional.

Answer (score 0):

¿Te funciona si independizas o parametrizas los datos respecto a la parte del código? Así esa información podría estar en un archivo json, o incluso en una base de datos que pudieran manejar otros sistemas, algo así:

```php
<?php
$conf = [ // Valores de ejemplo
    ['desde'=>'00:00', 'hasta'=>'00:30', 'link'=>'link1.php'],
    ['desde'=>'00:31', 'hasta'=>'01:45', 'link'=>'link2.php'],
    ['desde'=>'01:45', 'hasta'=>'03:59', 'link'=>'link3.php'],
    ['desde'=>'04:00', 'hasta'=>'10:14', 'link'=>'link4.php'],
    // ... etc hasta las 23:59
];

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$hora_actual = date('H:i');
foreach($conf as $interval) {
    if($hora_actual >= $interval['desde'] && $hora_actual <= $interval['hasta']) {
        echo $interval['link'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, disculpa que te responda hasta ahora, y muchisimas gracias, tu codigo me funcionó perfectamente para otro sistema mas complejo